# Postgres WITH Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

For simplicity, imagine that my table has one column, where total is an integer. Here, I expect the foo subquery to increment the total by 1, and the bar to decrement by 1, resulting in the same starting value. However, when I run this query, the total value is incremented. Why is this the case, and how can I solve this issue?

```
WITH 
foo AS (
UPDATE table SET total = total - 1 WHERE id = 10
RETURNING *
),
bar AS (
UPDATE table SET total = total + 1 WHERE id = 10
RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: It works correctly on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a2e48/1.  I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Because your `bar` is incrementing and your `foo` is decreasing by 1

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: I'm using version 9.4. Also, I expect the value to stay the same, but it is incrementing.

Comment: @dmwong2268 Your query works fine. Please provide your real table details and your real query.